# Suspicious userAgent- very long and full of some macro language

Tags: user-agent, malicious

My site was visited several hundred times in an hour by somebody using a very long (>5k characters) UserAgent. The query was the same every time but the UserAgent text varied, and possibly contained some malicious macro language.

Is there any maximum reasonable length for UserAgent text, beyond which I could reasonably ignore the query and/or block the IP address?